# MSBuild BuildDependsOn target for release builds only?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I would like to add a build target to the BuildDependsOn, but I want it to only affect release builds. How do I do this in MSBuild?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a condition when you override the `BuildDependsOn` property :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
...
<BuildDependsOn Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  BeforeBuild;
  CoreBuild;
  AfterBuild;
  NewBuildTarget;
</BuildDependsOn>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add

```
Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'"
```

to the `<Target>`.

Comment: What if it is a predefined target that i can not edit, such as "Package"?

Comment: Then I think I like @madgnome's answer.